# InfoPath 2013 SharePoint Online Switch Views New., Manager, Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, infopath-view

I have a web browser infopath form that has 3 views.  Default view is the New once it is submitted an email is route to the Manager (view=Manager) based on permissions the view should show the Manager view with the additional fields.  The last view is ADMIN it has all of the fields from the first two views so at anytime they can review the form.  I need to have it when the Manager clicks the link in the email it takes them to the Manager view and only shows that information.  I need to have the same ability for the email that is also sent to the Admin of the new request to show the Admin Form.  Regardless of the email when ever the User, Manager or Admin view the form from the library they are only seeing the view that matches the role.

I have tried several solution but nothing is working.  I do not want to use a button to change views I want it to be associated to either the Group Permissions assigned in SharePoint, I already have the data connection set up or any other method suggested.

I have seen where no matter what the rule setup it is not allowing the Admin to see the all up view or the manager to see their view.

I really need help getting this work.

Thank you in advance.
Dorinda

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to switch InfoPath view based on SharePoint user group.

1. Check if the current user is a member of a SharePoint user group in InfoPath;

Information about how to check the user in InfoPath:

http://www.hishamqaddomi.ca/spg/index.php/sharepoint-2010/infopath-2010/65-checking-if-a-user-is-a-member-in-a-sharepoint-group-within-web-infopath-2010-forms

2. Using a form load rule to display a view based on the condition.

An article about how to display a InfoPath form view using a form load rule:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#__toc259533881

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9841c5e1-b906-4c44-971e-089096fc4fc4/restrict-an-infopath-view-to-a-group?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious